# Convert Json object into string in java

Tags: java

I got the the Json value from server as

```
{"User":   
        {"loginId":"Rajaa",
         "firstName":"Rajaa",
         "lastName":"Ramanathan",
         "emailId": "raja@yahoo.com",
         "creationDate":"2011-01-25T12:00:00+05:30",
         "lastUpdate":"2011-01-25T12:00:00+05:30",
         "updated":"2"}
}
```

I want to take `loginId`,`firstName` etc as a string.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use [*GSON*](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/), check [user guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

**Also See**

- [How-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Use json-simple http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/
check this decoding example http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples