# How to use built-in serializers and deserializers in Gson for info coming from a php based website?

Tags: java, php, json, serialization

I have to create a class that takes in information coming from a particular php website using `java.net.URL` and decode it from the `Json format` to `general format`?

How do i accomplish it with or with out using the built-in serializes and deserializes in `Gson library`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly

Comment: Please post your code, or example