# How deserialize complex objects with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I have some objects.
The purpose of these objects is "mount" a user profile.

```
public class Profile {

    private Long userId;
    private String userName;
    private String accessToken;
    private Map<Integer,Parameter> parameters;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String setUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Parameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(Map<Integer, Parameter> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

Parameter is generic.
Sometimes it is a `Parameter<Boolean>`,
sometimes Parameter is list of objects.
The goal is to prevent coupling with the server.

```
public class Parameter<T> {

    private String name;
    private T value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This is a sample of Json response (part) 
...

```
"accessToken": "token-bla-bla",
"userId": 28,
"userName": "xpto",
"parameters": {
  "1": {
    "name": "stores",
    "value": [
      {
        "code": 8268,
        "name": "Store One",
        "offers": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "applyDiscount",
    "value": true
  },
```

...

```
   "22": {
     "name": "sellers",
     "value": [
       {
         "id": 33,
         "nome": "John Meyer"
       }
     ]
   },
```

Any answer is welcome!
I've tested TypeToken,
Type and others samples of other answers,
but,
none work for me.

**edited**

Here is more code to explain the problem.

```
public void handlerAllParams(Profile profile){

        Map<Integer, Parameter> parameterMap = profile.getParameters();


        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Parameter> parameterEntry : profile.getParameters().entrySet()) {
            Integer pKey = parameterEntry.getKey();
            Parameter p = parameterEntry.getValue();
            switch (pKey) {
                case 1:
                    Parameter<ArrayList<Store>> storesParameter = parameterEntry.getValue();
                    List<Store> stores = storesParameter.getValue();
                    handleStores(stores);
                    break;
```

The method `handleStores` should be transform "part of Json" parameter "1" in ArrayList of Store object.
But,
the result is LinkedTreeMap,
when I try convert the result is "malformed" name field of store one.
If I have other parameters like Parameter its ok,
but when I have Parameter> it cannot deserialize.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Google's Gson API to deserialize JSON properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly)

Comment: Please elaborate more. Question not clear.

Comment: Dears, please see more details in edited version. Sorry my trash english..

Comment: Can you post both json response ? Actually I didnt understand the point.

Comment: Krish, parameters is a Map. In my question, you see: parameter key "1" is array of Store object. The point is: i need polymorfic class know Parameter. Sometimes Parameter VALUE is ArrayList<Store> sometimes may be ArrayList<Bla>. I get the parameter by key, for example 1. and get value, I use this value with TypeToken as:  Type listOfStoresType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Store>>() {}.getType(); and pass by fromJson. The result is "malformed", but Json response is not malformed :-). Please, tell me if you can understand now. Regards! :-)

Comment: Did you get your issue resolved?