# Deserializing JSON array of objects using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

This is one in a row of deserialization questions but I've read them all and can't figure out the solution for my problem.

I need to get all the "entery"->"content" ->$t and "entery"->"title"->"$t" but in CategoryDeserializer() I get JsonArray that is NULL. I've pointed to that part of the code with "<====".

Error message:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator
>   java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference

I have JSON that looks something like this:

```
{  "feed":{  
      "id":{ ... },
      "author":[ ... ],
      "entry":[  
         {  
            "id":{  },
            "updated":{  },
            "category":[  ],
            "title":{ 
                "type":"text",
                "$t":"A1 },
            "content":{  
               "type":"text",
               "$t":"test"
            },
            "link":[  ]
         },
         { ... },
         { ... },
         {  ...},
      ]
   }
}
```

This is part of my code where I try to deserialize "entery":

```
String json = response.body().toString();

Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Entry>>() {
                            }.getType();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(listType, new CategoryDeserializer()).create();

List<Entry> list = gson.fromJson(json, listType);

for (Entry entry : list) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Content: " + entry.getContent());}
```

Where CategoryDeserializer() looks like this:

```
public class CategoryDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Entry>> {
public List<Entry> deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {

      JsonArray entry = je.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("entry");  //<==== here I get that entry is null but je has a value
      ArrayList<Entry> myList = new ArrayList<Entry>();

      for (JsonElement e : entry) {
           myList.add((Entry) jdc.deserialize(e, Entry.class));
      }

    return myList;}
```

And my Entry class:

```
public class Entry {

    private Id_ id;

    private Updated_ updated;

    private List<Category_> category = null;

    private Title_ title;

    private Content content;

    private List<Link_> link = null;

    //getters and setters

    public Id_ getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id_ id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Updated_ getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Updated_ updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    public List<Category_> getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(List<Category_> category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Title_ getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(Title_ title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Content getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public List<Link_> getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(List<Link_> link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

}
```

Edit: I have declaration and instantiation.

Comment: did you see this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly

Comment: you can use this > 
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(s.toString(), Entry.class);

Comment: But if you can show json data completely it would be good to help.

Comment: @Milaci Yes, I saw that. When I write  Entry[] entry = gson.fromJson(textTable, Entry[].class); I get  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference.

Comment: @DevSabby here is the gist with JSON. https://gist.github.com/deedora/98a8aadb08312a46f4627e6754339033
Unfortunately the first answer doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was complicating things that were not complicated. All I had to do was this:

```
String json = response.body().toString();
Gson mGson = new Gson();

//where Example is the root of JSON
Example rsp = mGson.fromJson(json, Example.class);

//Entry is the list I needed to access
List <Entry> listOfEntrys= rsp.getFeed().getEntry();

//get value
Log.i("MainActivity", "listaEntrya " + listOfEntrys.get(0).getTitle().get$t());
```