# Deserialize json in java with gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having a very tough time deserializing json in java with gson.

I have the following json:

```
{"races":[
{"id":1,"mask":1,"side":"alliance","name":"Human"},
{"id":2,"mask":2,"side":"horde","name":"Orc"},
{"id":3,"mask":4,"side":"alliance","name":"Dwarf"}]}
```

The java code I have now is:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<WoWDetails>>(){}.getType();
                    List<WoWRaces> races = gson.fromJson(response, type);
                    for (WoWRaces race : races){
                        if(raceID.equals(race.id)) {
                            raceName = race.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            errorMSG = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. textView5);
            errorMSG.setText("That didn't work! URL: \n"+error);
            errorMSG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

In WoWRaces.java is the following code:

**WoWRaces.java**

```
public class WoWRaces {
   public Integer id;
   public String name;
}
```

It's giving me the following error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

I have searched and visited multiple questions but I can't seem to figure this out. The data that I would need is the id and the name bound to it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you want to parse the JSON?

Comment: Use gson library . it would be very easy

Comment: Yes I want to Parse it, and I am using gson, yet I can't seem to figure it out :/

Comment: Describe exactly what is your problem: you say there is a problem, but don't say what problem it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Google's Gson API to deserialize JSON properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly)

Comment: post your java code where ur using gson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing using Gson for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)

Comment: *I have searched and visited multiple questions but I can't seem to figure this out* try reading the docs

Comment: I updated my question and hope it's more clear now, I have looked in the docs and other questions but I couldn't figure it out myself, hense the question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using gson library then try this

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MainResponse mainResponse = gson.fromJson(response, MainResponse.class);
    List<Race> races = mainResponse.getRaces();
    for (Race race : races) {
        Log.e("TEST","Race id : " + race.getId());
        Log.e("TEST","Race Name : " + race.getName());
    }
```

MainResponse.java

```
public class MainResponse {

    @SerializedName("races")
    @Expose
    private List<Race> races = null;

    public List<Race> getRaces() {
        return races;
    }

    public void setRaces(List<Race> races) {
        this.races = races;
    }

}
```

Race.java

```
public class Race {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("mask")
    @Expose
    private int mask;
    @SerializedName("side")
    @Expose
    private String side;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getMask() {
        return mask;
    }

    public void setMask(int mask) {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    public String getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(String side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes..create ItemResponse and Item class then you can do same thing as you have done previously.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Create `RacesResponse` class as:

```
 public class RacesResponse {

     @SerializedName("races")
     public List<WowRaces> list;
 }
```

**2.** Change your code to:

```
RacesResponse racesResponse = gson.fromJson(response, RacesResponse.class);
List<WowRaces> races = racesResponse.list;
```

Comment: This is correct. The error 'Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT' the SO gets, is because via your TypeToken he tells Gson to expect an array, but the JSON response is an object (containing one array). This answer here adresses this correctly.

Comment: I will try this too, thank you for taking your time to help me!

Comment: I can't upvote yet, I just made this account, I will when I can!

Answer (score 1):

you can put your json string [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and copy all classes in your app and use main class to in the `new Gson.fromJson(jsonString,Example.class)`

> in the url select this option

1. Source type:Json
2. Annotation style:Gson