# Parsing Dynamic JSON node with retrofit gson

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I'm using Woo-Commerce RestApi v2, using `Retrofit` for api calling. when I'm fetching all category. There was a node name `image`, it returns blank array but when image uploaded it returns object. Here is my JSON sample

```
[
    {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Albums",
    "slug": "albums",
    "parent": 11,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 4
    },
    {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Clothing",
    "slug": "clothing",
    "parent": 0,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": {
    "id": 730,
    "date_created": "2017-03-23T00:01:07",
    "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:01:07",
    "date_modified": "2017-03-23T00:01:07",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:01:07",
    "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_front.jpg",
    "title": "",
    "alt": ""
    },
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 36
    }
]
```

The main problem with image node.
How to create model class for that node. I used jsonschema2pojo.org for generate model class but that class only works, When I remove `image` from class.
can you guide me what to do?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 ApiInterface apiService= ApiClient.getWooCommerceClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<List<Category>> call=apiService.getAllCategories();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Category>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Category>> response) {
            categoryList.addAll(response.body());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Category>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

Use `Image` as `String`

**Category**

```
public class Category {
/**
 * id : 15
 * name : Albums
 * slug : albums
 * parent : 11
 * description :
 * display : default
 * image : []
 * menu_order : 0
 * count : 4
 */

private int id;
private String name;
private String slug;
private int parent;
private String description;
private String display;
private int menu_order;
private int count;
private String image;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public int getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(int parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDisplay() {
    return display;
}

public void setDisplay(String display) {
    this.display = display;
}

public int getMenu_order() {
    return menu_order;
}

public void setMenu_order(int menu_order) {
    this.menu_order = menu_order;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

Use in response

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Category>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Category>> response) {
    categoryList.addAll(response.body());
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {
        if(!categoryList.get(i).getImage().contains("[")){
            image = categoryList.get(i).getImage();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(image);
                String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("your_key");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If it contains `[`,you can't do any thing .

Else you can parse it in your code .

Comment: Looks like elegant solution. i will accept this answers after testing.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by removing the `@Expose` annotation and use `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();` at the `Gson` constructor. The unfounded data will be set to `null`.

Comment: can you provide some code snippet. i'm new to GSON.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly