# How would i get a specific variable in response body after a POST request

Tags: java, android, json, request, response

I am building an android app that is supposed to edit documents it can get from a remote server. However, to do so i need the user to log in. This should happen like this:

User types in userId and password, POST is sent with this body:

```
    {
     "username": "normal_username",
     "password": "normal_password"
    }
```

and when i do so in postman the response body looks like this
        {
         "username": "normal_username",
         "token": "lotsandlotsofnumbersandletters"
        }

I want to retrieve this token, but i dont know how to do so in android, are there any external libraries that could make this easier for me perhaps?

Comment: You're looking for a json deserializer. I recommend GSON. Jackson is another option. Using Android or just Java probably won't make a difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly

Comment: I combined GSON with the Retrofit library and got it working, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the response body is JSON, you need to parse it. Use a library such as GSON to do so then you can easily grab the value of the `"token"` key.

You also might want to look at a library that wraps the entire REST API. [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) from Square is one of the most popular libraries that does this.

Comment: Thanks. I used GSON, and the Retrofit library made the whole process alot more easier and readable.