# How to extract certain data from a string in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

My application makes API calls and receives data in a single string.
The data looks something like this: [{"city_mpg": 16, "cylinders": 6, "displacement": 2.8}]

My plan was to extract data from this string and assign it to variables
ex. `var cylinders = 6`

Is that even possible?

EDIT:

After following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly) I solved the problem with ease. Turns out i was looking at it wrong.

Comment: `My plan was to extract data from this string and assign it to variables ex. var cylinders = 6` can you show how you tried to do this ? could it be that this data is perhaps using a common format, like Json, which you could parse and make your life simpler ? `I tried using .contains() but to no avail.` what does contains do ? how did you try to use that to solve your problem here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This string is in JSON format. To extract data to variables use something like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), which is a library build for deserialising json strings into objects. For a detailed description, on how to use GSON please check out this [link](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/UserGuide.md) or this Stack Overflow question about the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864370/how-do-i-use-googles-gson-api-to-deserialize-json-properly).